# camera throwing IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I've seen another similar thread and tried their suggestions but same issue occurs so I didnit want to hijack their thread so I am posting a different thread.Sorry.

Anyway, I am trying to create a camera application using Eclipse and Android 4.2.2 api. Whenever I debug or run the application on my device I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException`. I appreicate if someone could look into this here is my logcat trace:

```
06-02 15:35:32.069: W/dalvikvm(12329): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d46930)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at  android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    ... 11 more
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1095)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1040)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    at com.example.de.vogella.camera.api.MakePhotoActivity.onClick(MakePhotoActivity.java:46)
06-02 15:35:32.069: E/AndroidRuntime(12329):    ... 14 more
```

I have tried the following code in the `onClick()` method and I still get the same error when I try and use the app:

```
if(camera == null)
{
// Warn user that camera is not available via "Toast" or similar.
} else {
camera.takePicture(null, null,new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()))
}
```

I also tried the following. I declared `mPhotoHandler` at top of the class where I keep my other variables and within the `onClick()` method I put only this code in:

```
mPhotoHandler = new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext());
camera.takePicture(null, null,mPhotoHandler);
```

Here is the code for my `onPause()` method:

```
protected void onPause() {
    if (camera != null) {
      camera.release();
      camera = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
  }
```

Is there something wrong with the above code? Please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried to replace getApplicationContext() with MakePhotoActivity.this?

Comment: Do you see the camera preview before you click the button?

Comment: I have tried and replaced it with MakePhotoActivity.this and the same error occurs.
Alex, i do not see the camera preview before i click the button. The error occurs when i click the
button.